# Trigonometric Complex Integral Question

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the value of the integral $\oint_{\gamma} \frac{z}{\cos z}$, where

$\gamma$ is the circle $|z|= 5$ in the counterclockwise direction

Comment: I've tried parametrising the path and taking the path integral, but it gets very messy. I think i need some kind of manipulation of cos z, or a residue.

Comment: Did you try using residues?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use residues to compute this.

Comment: hint: there are four poles inside your contour:
$z=\pm \pi/2 , \pm 3 \pi/2$ calculate them and add them up and u are done (the result should be zero)

Comment: so for example, at $\pi/2$ , Res =lim  $(z-\pi/2)z$ / $\cos z)$ = $(z^2 -( (1/2) \pi z))$/ $\cos z$ = 0?

Answer (score 2):

First notice that the only poles of the function $f(z)=\frac{z}{\cos z}$ are when $\cos z=0$, so they are the points $\pi/2+k\pi$. Since we're integrating inside the circle $|z|=5$ the only poles that matter are $\pm \pi$ and $\pm 3/2\pi$. Next we have to find the residues at the poles, that can be done for example computing the limit
$$\lim_{z \to \pi/2} \frac{z}{-\sin \frac{\pi}{2}}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
where I used the fact that $(\cos z)'=-\sin z$. Using the same argument we can find the other residues: $3/2\pi$, $3/2\pi$, $-\pi/2$. 
Residues theorem tell us that the integral along the path is just the sum of the residues multiplied by $2\pi i$:

$$2\pi i\Big(-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{2}\Big)=4\pi^2i$$

Comment: but the residues should have opposite signs right?

Comment: From my calculation, thay have not.

Comment: ok u are right, the signs from the sin and from z cancel each other. (+1)